# Can't get while loop to work 2 times? (C)

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

**So I'm trying to loop the name asking section as well as the age one, the age one worked fine but when I tried to do it with name one it doesn't work. What I'm just trying to achieve is that when you put a number in the name section or vice versa, you get an error message and it loops you back to the same question**

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int vek;
char name[20];
int result1;
int result2;

int main()
{
    FindName();
void FindName() { // it wants me to put a ";" which doesn't make sense to me and doesn't work
    printf("Napis svoje meno \n");
    result2 = scanf("%s",&name);
    while (gethar() != '\n');
    if(result2 == 1){
         printf("Ahoj %s \n",name);
         break;
         system("pause");
    }
    else {
         printf("nepis sem cisla ty kokot \n");
         }
    
    findAge();
} 

void findAge() {
    printf("Napis svoj vek \n");
    result1 = scanf("%d",&vek);

    while (getchar() != '\n');
    if(result1 == 1){
        printf("%s si krasny %d rocny priklad downoveho syndromu  \n ",&name,vek);
    }
    else {
        printf("co si jebnuty \n");
        findAge();
    } 
}
```

**I've tried  to just break the loop if it's the right answer but that wouldn't work either, I'm just a beginner**

Comment: You forgot a `}` after `main()`.

Comment: problem still remains

Comment: No, it doesn't work. You need to read about how `while` loops work. The age one "works" but not thanks to the while loop either. It only works because you recursively call it when the user doesn't input a number.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop will run everything inside the body as long as the condition is true. You need to put the code that needs to be repeated in a block, between `{` and `}`. You've put a semicolon behind it. That means a null statement, or *do nothing*. That way the condition is checked until it is no longer true, but nothing else is done. For example:

```
int i=0;
while(i < 3) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    i++;
}
```

That will print the numbers 0,1 and 2. And then it stops because the condition is no longer true.

You want the program to look like this. In *pseudocode*:

```
main:
    call findName
    call findAge

findName:
    print "Something Eastern European asking for a name"
    result = 0;
    while result != 1:
        result = read input
        if result == 0
            print "Try again"
```

And the same for `findAge`

Notice the functions never call themselves. They just run the loop until the input is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the response but uppon trying to replicate this im still doing something wrong